# What was the stuff Dr. Destiny attempted to inject into batman?

Tags: dc, dc-animated-universe, justice-league

In *Justice League* Season 2 Episode 6, Dr. Destiny attempts to inject batman with this fluid, however he fails and injects himself. In this next scene it looks like he turns to stone. What was he trying to inject batman with?

Comment: Maybe Medusa juice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bottle says [Eccaine](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=DvbJCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA213&lpg=PA213&dq=%22eccaine%22&source=bl&ots=nSsg7PSOKq&sig=3XezHxI3ThaAU2f9iBb7rwxPiuY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjh1rCDisfbAhXQSsAKHZeYDdk4ChDoAQg7MAQ#v=onepage&q=%22eccaine%22&f=false), a synthetic substance similar to cocaine but more powerful and volatile.

[image]

Comment: Cocaine is a stimulant though, and most substances with the suffix "-caine" are local anaesthetics, not general anaesthetics like Dee would want to use as he has power to influence people more strongly while they're unconscious.

Comment: @DomVasta - Well, the visible effects don't match Eccaine in the slightest so it's probably Eccaine *plus* some other stuff

Comment: Seems like the link says "You have reached your viewing limit for this book" when I click on Eccaine. I wonder what it was about.

Comment: @Clockwork - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dpusq.png

Answer (score -2):

It's most likely a drug they use to keep certain Prisoners calm so they can be safe around them and not go on a rampage. That or it's something else.

Comment: A calming drug turns someone to stone? Also you should try and find some evidence for this that you could [edit] in to back up your claims.